Do FSA administrators have the option to challenge a medical necessity?
If I have a valid letter of medical necessity for a Herman Miller ergonomic chair which is $2,000. Do FSA administrators have the option to challenge or reject that letter of medical necessity or can I make the purchase without concern for a challenge? How concerned about the cost should I be about a purchase of an ergonomic chair I like, if my doctor signs to it being a necessity?
Do they have an incentive to deny the claim for my own money?

This question assumes a valid letter signed by a qualified medical practitioner for a qualified medical expense.

I just called up my own FSA provider Benefit Resource at ‪(800) 473-9595‬. I spoke to Tayla who informed me that as an FSA administrator they will never "challenge" claims that are properly filed on the cost of the chair.
She said the IRS does challenge claims, but only if

They're not filed properly (meeting the criteria here) pay attention to the note requiring an explicit "medical condition"
They don't have a receipt.
They have reason to believe the chair is not ergonomic, which is required to be a qualified purchase.

I expressed concern about the cost of the chair I was wanting to purchase, and she said there is no problem after a doctor declared it medically necessary and you can show that's what the funds were used to purchase.
The Herman Miller Chair I'm purchasing is advertised as "engineered to encourage movement, support a range of postures (from active and upright to reclined and relaxed), eliminate pressure buildup, and even keep you cool with an extra layer of copper-infused foam". And, it has "Backfit™ Adjustment automatically conforms to your spine’s unique shape and movements."
This mention of ergonomics make it a clear "ergonomic chair." If the doctor signs a letter of medical necessity and I have a receipt, she says I have no reason to be concerned with the purchase.

You asked if they have an option, not if your administrator will challenge.

@littleadv a reasonable point but my FSA administrator has been explicit they will not challenge. I can't speak for all administrators to whether they can or not, but your answer doesn't justify your conclusion.. I'll drop the comment there.

The Herman Miller chair advertising just sounds like a chair. One was typical office adjustments mind you, but a chair. It may in fact have good ergonomics - in fact I expect it to be excellent since that's what hm's big selling point is - but that description does not make it sound any better than many other chairs available for a fraction of the price. It may in fact be worth the money, but don't expect that particular quote to convince anyone.

@keshlam It doesn't have to convince anyone. This is why the other answer is wrong. It's an ergonomic chair. I only have to convince my doctor that it's medical necessary. He doesn't have to answer to anyone. The IRS doesn't have a mechanism to dispute the purchase on the price. Any chair that's "ergonomic" is for IRS purposes "medically necessary" if your doctor agrees.

If you say so. Personally I would expect this to trigger an audit. But it you're sure it will be approved, that's nothing more than annoying.

It may be audited, but that doesn't change anything. That's not the question. There are no grounds for rejection with a (1) valid letter of medical necessity, (2) qualified purchase, (3) valid receipt.

@keshlam see the update

Yes, if the FSA administrator believes that the letter will not pass the IRS scrutiny they can challenge it. The IRS challenges those all the time, especially in the scenario you're presenting. Here's one recent write-up:

Key Takeaway: Be cautious about aggressive marketing that promotes everyday expenses as reimbursable medical costs. Always follow IRS rules when using your HSA or FSA funds properly. Or consult a tax professional.

Even if you find a doctor that writes a letter that determines that only a $2000 Herman Miller chair can help your health, it is unlikely to be a reasonable medical assessment and I can see how it could easily be challenged.

This is not what the FSA administrator told me when I called up just to be clear. She contradicted this entirely.

@EvanCarroll from the answer you wrote it seems that that's exactly what your FSA administrator told you. She said that they won't challenge that because they believe the IRS won't challenge that.

I agree my answer is what my FSA admin WILL NOT challenge cost. But this answer doesn't address can either. You've shown "follow IRS rules when using your HSA or FSA funds properly" and concluded "unlikely to be a reasonable medical assessment" you've not shown anywhere that the FSA administrator can make a "reasonable medical assessment". Mine categorically said they won't. But you haven't shown they can. Under what terms can an FSA administrator find "medically necessary" purchases unreasonable based on cost?

@EvanCarroll my challenged the medical necessity letter written by a PT (even though they were not supposed to), but accepted it when it was signed by a PA. So I'm not entirely sure how categorical that is. The medical necessity is not based on cost, as I said - for me it was a $10 item. It's based on intended use, and whether the necessity letter is deemed trustworthy. For example, in the article they said that letters given without examination would be challenged.

@EvanCarroll as to "unlikely to be a reasonable medical assessment" - my personal take is that if a doctor requires a specific brand of equipment - that can be challenged. If a doctor requires "an ergonomic chair" and your FSA deems the Herman Miller one acceptable - then you're good to go.

Your conclusion says _"Even if you find a doctor that writes a letter that determines that only a $2000 Herman Miller chair can help your health, it is unlikely to be a reasonable medical assessment"_is not a sound conclusion from your premise. You haven't shown that it's unlikely to be a reasonable medical assessment at all, never mind on the basis of it being a "$2000 Herman Miller chair": which seems to be at odds with "the medical necessity is not based on cost". Exactly! Getting a chair is a "medical necessity" the cost is irrelevant, so long as the doctor agrees with necessity.

And the PT/PA component may make the letter of medical necessity invalid, but it doesn't have much to do with the question: how concerned about the cost should I be about the ergonomic chair I like if my doctor signs to it being necessary?

@EvanCarroll you got an answer specific to your situation from your provider, why are you badgering me? The brand of a chair is not determined by the medical necessity, only it's function. I've never had a medical necessity letter mention a specific brand, and never needed one. You seem to be more concerned about the brand than the function, which to me suggests that you're not in fact motivated by the actual medical necessity. Whether the IRS will challenge it or not is up to the IRS, but I think they can.

Why would the FSA administrator care if the expense was valid? If it is challenged by the IRS then wouldn't the taxes and penalties be the responsibility of the individual? I don't think the administrator would face any consequences.

@Nosjack unused FSA funds get forfeited
